# font awesome not showing from bootstrap theme and im using eclipse

Tags: css, eclipse, twitter-bootstrap, fonts, font-awesome

im just a newbie and im trying to use agency start bootstrap theme. im using eclipse, and i tried to modify the home.jsp to locate the css and scripts but the font awesome and glyphicons are not showing. here is what i did.

```
<!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
<style type="text/css"><%@include file="resources/css/bootstrap.min.css" %></style> 

<!-- Custom CSS -->
<style type="text/css"><%@include file="resources/css/agency.css" %></style>


<!-- Custom Fonts -->
 <style type="text/css"><%@include file="resources/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" %></style>
```

i hope you could help me, because i tried searching for solution on net but i wasnt able to find one that helps. thanks

Comment: Is the bootstrap css loading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i gave up on tracing where this is located

```
<!-- Custom Fonts -->
<style type="text/css"><%@include file="resources/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" %></style>
```

i tried getting the source online and it worked, 
here is my solution:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the font-awesome folder in your project root, it has a fonts folder that the css uses to include the icons.

```
<!-- Custom Fonts -->
 <style type="text/css"><%@include file="/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" %></style>
```

Comment: font-awesome folder is in the project already as stated in the path i included. but still the font-awesome fonts and icons are not showing.

Comment: When you run your site, what are the console errors? Does it say that it cant find one of the .woff, .woff2, .ttf, .svg, .eot font files?

Comment: there are no console errors. im just being shown blank squares from where the icons should appear after loading on my browser. i would love to show the structure of my folders however i dont have enough badges to post an image with my question :(

Comment: I have seen this before, it's not finding the font files. Is the font-awesome folder in the ROOT of your project?

Comment: Here is the structure of my folders:
>WebContent
     >WEB-INF
         >views
             >resources
                 >font-awesome

where should i place it here?

Comment: i also have this in my context.xml.

     <annotation-driven />
  <resources mapping="/img/**" location="/img/" />
 
  <mvc:resources mapping="/img/**" location="/img/" />

Comment: Sorry, it is too hard to explain.

Comment: by the way, i also used the edited code that you gave and tracked its directory and placed a font-awesome folder there but still wont work. @Hanoncs :(

Comment: HI all, still would like to say that i havent solved this yet. help would be a big thing. thanks :)